# Children's story about a mouse with a noise in the house

Tags: identification-request

I'm trying to find a story from my childhood. It was about a mouse that was worried about a noise in its house every night. The mouse asked all of the other animals to help it find the source of the noise, that ended up being an owl that lived in the mouse's attic.

I remember it being in a collection of short stories that was already pretty old in the early 90s.

Any help would be much appreciated!